# How does Apache spark structured streaming 2.3.0 let the sink know that a new row is an update of an existing row?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

How does spark structured streaming let the sink know that a new row is an update of an existing row when run in an **update mode**? Does it look at all the values of all columns of the new row and an existing row for an equality match or does it compute some sort of hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#basic-concepts), we see some interesting information about update mode (bold formatting added by me):

> Update Mode - Only the rows that were updated in the Result Table since the last trigger will be written to the external storage (available since Spark 2.1.1). Note that this is different from the Complete Mode in that this mode only outputs the rows that have changed since the last trigger. **If the query doesn’t contain aggregations, it will be equivalent to Append mode**.

So, to use update mode there needs to be some kind of aggregation otherwise all data will simply be added to the end of the result table. In turn, to use aggregation the data need to use one or more coulmns as a key. Since a key is needed it is easy to know if a row has been updated or not - simply compare the values with the previous iteration of the table (the key tells you which row to compare with). In aggregations that contains a `groupby`, the columns being grouped on  are the keys.

Simple aggregations that return a single value will not require a key. However, since only a single value is returned it will update if that value is changed. An example here could be taking the sum of a column (without groupby).

The documentation contains a picture that gives a good understanding of this, see the "Model of the Quick Example" from the link above.

Comment: Thanks for this! The big question here is what is a key for a given aggregation query? say I do `select count(*) from view1)` or `select sum(col1), max(col2) from view2` or `select max(time_stamp) from view1 group by id` or `select col1 from (select max(time_stamp) from view1 group by id) `

Comment: can you tell me what key would be for these 4 queries?

Comment: @user1870400 The first two doesn't actually need any key since they will be a single value, if the value change it can be updated (I will add this to the answer). The last two have `group by id`, so I'd will be the key in those.

Comment: Thanks again.  how is this key exposed if I were to extend an existing sink to support update mode? For example, ES-hadoop-connector currently only supports append mode I am trying to understand how these things work so I can implement update mode for it.

Comment: @user1870400: I'm not sure about that, sorry. Maybe this site can help you somewhat: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/spark-structured-streaming/spark-sql-streaming-demo-custom-sink-webui.html. I also saw there is a JIRA ticket for adding update mode to the ES-hadoop-connector on github: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/issues/1123.